# WordPress blocks API JSX not rerendering after setAttributes called

Tags: wordpress, jsx, gutenberg-blocks

I have creaded a wordpress gutenburg block api JSX component,
It's uses the passed props attributes and setAttributes.

I have used a map function to render a set of `divs` based on the attribute 'slides'.  I am pushing a object onto the array using an onClick event handler, the event is called and the object is added to the array, I then set the slides variable using setAttributes.  However after doing this the component is not rerendered.

Code

```
  const Edit = (props) => {
    let {
      attributes: { slides },
      setAttributes,
    } = props;


    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    const onChangeTitle = (value, test) => {
      console.log(getChildIndex(value.target.parentNode));

      /* getChildIndex()
      slides;
      setAttributes({ title: value });*/
    };

  

    const addSlide = () => {
      slides.push({
        title: "",
        description: "",
        media: [],
      });

      setAttributes({ slides: slides });
    };

  

    return (
      <div {...blockProps}>
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <div className="hero-slide">
            <RichText
              tagName="h2"
              placeholder={__("Hero Slide Title", "gutenberg-examples")}
              value={slide.title}
              onChange={onChangeTitle}
            />
            <RichText
              tagName="p"
              placeholder={__("Hero Slide Content", "gutenberg-examples")}
              value={slide.title}
              onChange={onChangeContent}
            />
            <div contentEditable onInput={onChangeTitle}>
              test
            </div>
            <div className="hero-image">
              <MediaUpload
                onSelect={onSelectImage}
                allowedTypes="image"
                value=""
                render={({ open }) => (
                  <Button className={"image-button"} onClick={open}>
                    {typeof mediaID == "undefined" ? (
                      __("Upload Image", "gutenberg-examples")
                    ) : (
                      <div>Test</div>
                    )}
                  </Button>
                )}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Button className="add-slide" onClick={addSlide}>
          Add Hero Slide
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the array to rerender:

```
const addSlide = () => {
   const emptySlide = {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      media: [],
   };

   setAttributes({ slides: [...slides, emptySlide] });
 };
```